# Regular expression to match a word that contains ONLY one colon

Tags: regex

I am new to regex, basically I'd like to check if a word has ONLY one colons or not.

If has two or more colons, it will return nothing.
if has one colon, then return as it is. (colon must be in the middle of string, not end or beginning.

(1)

```
a:bc:de  #return nothing or error.
```

```
a:bc    #return a:bc
```

```
a.b_c-12/:a.b_c-12/ #return a.b_c-12/:a.b_c-12/
```

(2)

My thinking is, but this is seems too complicated.

```
^[^:]*(\:[^:]*){1}$
```

```
^[-\w.\/]*:[-\w\/.]*   #this will not throw error when there are 2 colons.
```

Any directions would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Should just be `^[^:]+:[^:]+$` - anything but a colon (repeated), a colon, anything but a colon (repeated), anchored at both ends.

Comment: What language/environment will you be implementing your sought solution in?

Comment: @jasonharper Please do not intentionally breech the simple page design of this Q & A site by posting resolving advice as a comment under the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find such "words" within a larger sentence:

```
(?<= |^)[^ :]+:[^ :]+(?= |$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/WA49tgrmU6BTbD).

If you just want to test the whole input:

```
^[^ :]+:[^ :]+$
```

---

To restrict to only alphanumeric, underscore, dashes, dots, and slashes:

```
^[\w./-]+:[\w./-]+$
```

Comment: Thanks! ^[^ :]+:[^ :]+$ this works. But what if I only want to have number, letters, dash,underscore, dot, to be repeated, not other characters. This will work, i guess, ^[^:][-\w.\_]*+:[^:]+$

Comment: @Xiaolong see edited answer. Note: `\w` includes the underscore. Your example had slashes so I addd them too.

Comment: ^[\w.\/-]+:[\w.\/-]+$ is correct

Answer (score 0):

I saw this as a good opportunity to brush up on my regex skills - so might not be optimal but it is shorter than your last solution.

This is the regex pattern: `/^[^:]*:[^:]*$/gm` and these are the strings I am testing against: `'oneco:on'` (match) and `'one:co:on'`, `'oneco:on:'`, `':oneco:on'` (these should all not match)

To explain what is going on, the `^` matches the beginning of the string, the `$` matches the end of the string.

The `[^:]` bit says that any character that is *not* a colon will be matched.

In summary, `^[^:]` means that the first character of the string can be anything *except* for a colon, `*:` means that any number of characters can come after and be followed by a *single* colon. Lastly, `[^:]*$` means that any number (`*`) of characters can follow the colon as long as *they* are not a colon.

To elaborate, it is because we specify the pattern to look for at the beginning and end of the string, surrounding the single colon we are looking for that only the first string `'oneco:on'` is a match.

Comment: Just a colon `:` will work exactly the same as `:{1}`!

Comment: Thanks @PoulBak ! Definitely missed that. I will edit my answer.